# How do you make multiple animations start from clicking one object?

Tags: animation, aframe

I've started learning a-frame recently and I'm trying to create a domino effect type thing. I want all of my animations to start after I click on the first object. I've tried using delay but the delay starts immediately instead of after I start the animation. How do I make it so after someone clicks object 1, object 2's animation would start shortly after?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try the **delay** approach - with a custom component for some managment :)

---

Lets say you have a setup like this (html pseudocode):

```
<a-box class='domino' foo animation='startEvents: go; ...
<a-box class='domino' animation='startEvents: go; delay: 200 ...
<a-box class='domino' animation='startEvents: go; delay: 400 ...
```

All items have some attributes / components:

- The **class** attribute to make them easy to both grab and distinguish from any other entities.
- The **animation** component which will make them animate - whats important: `startEvents` - here we'll throw the event which will be emitted simultaneously on all boxes, `delay` - so every next box will wait before moving.
- This **foo** component - we'll [make it by ourselves](https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/introduction/writing-a-component.html#sidebar). It will detect a mouseclick, and emit the `go` event on all boxes.

So the concept is as follows:

1. We click one box with the `foo` component
2. the `foo` component detects the click and emits `go` on all `.domino` elements
3. all `.domino` elements should start their animations one after another - but each one 200ms later than the previous one.

---

Now lets make the custom component. Keep in mind it has to be defined **before** the `<a-scene>`:

```
<script src='component.js'></script>
<script>
   // component
</script>

<a-scene>
</a-scene>
```

We will implement all logic within the `init` function - which is called upon initialisation.

```
// component definition 
AFRAME.registerComponent('foo', {

  // this is called upon initialisation
  init: function() {

     // grab all the domino pieces
     var pieces = document.getElementsByClassName('domino')

     // if this one gets pressed...
     this.el.addEventListener('click', e => {

       // ...emit the event on all of them
       for (let piece of pieces) {
         piece.emit('go')
       }
     })
   }
})
```

and actually - thats it. To see it in action - here are two examples - in both clicking the blue box, should start the animation.

1. [Simple delayed animation cascade](https://jsfiddle.net/4z3x28mg/3/)
2. [Domino-like animation](https://jsfiddle.net/dmprza03/)

Comment: Not animation related - but this seems like a fun task for a [physics engine](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-physics-system). Check it out [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4z3x28mg/4/).

Comment: Can you go into a little more detail on where some of this would go? Specifically that second part. I'm pretty new to aframe so I'm still learning about a lot of this.

Comment: @Robbie is this better - or did I focus on the wrong parts :p

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks for the clarification! I'll award the bounty as soon as I can.

Comment: @Robbie glad i could help - also added a domino-like example.